# A* algorithm runs slowly in intellij

Tags: javascript, algorithm, intellij-idea

I'm developing a game like Clash of Clan (just an exercise). And I use a* algorithm for soldier to find the path to target. The size of map is 120 x 120.
But when a soldier find his target, it takes 4 to 5 second to find out his path. (the result is appropximately 120 steps, 5xxx node in open list).
That code when i run on browser, it just some miliseconds.

```
findPath: function (startTile, endTile, id, isIgnoreWall) {
        if (startTile.x === endTile.x && startTile.y === endTile.y)
            return [];
        if (!id)
            id = 0;
        var openPath = [], closePath = [];
        openPath[0] = {
            pos: startTile,
            parent: null,
            g: 0,
            f: this.calculateH(startTile, endTile)
        };

        var matrix = SceneMgr.getCurrentScene().getMapView().matrix;
        var isFound = false, k = 0;
        var _path = [];
        while (openPath.length) {

            var minIndex = this.findMin(openPath);
            var minNode = openPath[minIndex];
            openPath.splice(minIndex, 1);
            closePath.push(minNode);
            var aroundNode = this.findAroundNode(minNode.pos);
            for (var i = 0; i < aroundNode.length; i++) {

                var pos = aroundNode[i];
                var indexClose = this.getNodeIndex(pos, closePath);
                if (indexClose != -1 || !this.canMove(pos, isIgnoreWall, id, matrix))
                    continue;

                if (pos.x === endTile.x && pos.y === endTile.y) {
                    var node = {
                        pos: pos,
                        parent: minNode
                    };
                    var path = [];
                    cc.log("tim thay: ", closePath.length);
                    while (node.parent) {
                        path.unshift(node);
                        node = node.parent;
                    }

                    return path;
                    break;
            }

                var cost = this.calculateH(minNode.pos, pos);

                var g = minNode.g + cost;
                var h = this.calculateH(pos, endTile);
                var f = g + h;
                var newNode = {
                    pos: pos,
                    g: g,
                    f: f,
                    parent: minNode
                };

                var indexOpen = this.getNodeIndex(pos, openPath);
                //if node with the same pos is already in open list
                if (indexOpen != -1) {
                    //if node in open list has f less than f, then re-assign, else skip it
                    if (openPath[indexOpen].g > g) {
                        openPath[indexOpen] = newNode;
                    }
                } else {
                    openPath.push(newNode);
                    //_path.push({pos});
                    //this.draw([{pos}]);
                }
            }


        }
        return [];
    }
```

Comment: Please don't care about id and isIgnoreWall variables :D

Comment: could you clarify what you mean by running the code in IDEA? The IDE itself doesn't run your code, it's run either in browser or with Node.js interpreter, I don't believe that the issue has anything to do with the IDE

Comment: i don't know the reason. But when i copied this code and run it in chrome browser, it took some miliseconds to complete. But when i run in intellij, it's aboout 4 to 5 seconds.

Comment: how do you run it?